# Grunt exec - Gzip all minified css and js files in directory

Tags: command-line, find, sh

I want to gzip all minified files in the js and css folder only.

I picked this command line code over stackoverflow and modified it to look for minified css and js files.

```
for i in `find | grep -E "\.min.css$|\.min.js$"`; do gzip -k9 "$i" ; done
```

This command works but searches other directories as well. Not desirable since it searches the node_modules directory as well. How can i specify to look into js and css directory only.

I tried

```
css\.min.css$|js\.min.js$
```

but nothing happens. No errors, no files generated.

```
exec: {
    gzip: {
        command: 'for i in `find | grep -E "\.min.css$|\.min.js$"`; do gzip -k9 "$i" ; done',
        stdout: true,
        stderr: true
    }
}
```

**EDIT**
I looked up the man pages for find command and wrote two separate commands for each folder i.e js and css in my gruntfile.js.

Works perfectly but I suppose it can be done in one line using grep. Not yet sure how to do it.

```
exec: {
    gzipJs: {
        command: 'for i in `find js admin/assets -name "*.min.js"`; do gzip -k9 "$i" ; done',
        stdout: true,
        stderr: true
    },

    gzipCss: {
        command: 'for i in `find css admin/assets -name "*.min.css"`; do gzip -k9 "$i" ; done',
        stdout: true,
        stderr: true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you're just looking for

```
find admin/assets css js '(' -name '*.min.js' -o -name '*.min.css' ')' -exec gzip -k9 '{}' +
```

There's no need for `` ` ` `` or a `for` loop (which, by the way, will break if any of your filenames contain spaces).

Comment: Thanks for taking the time. Whats the {} and + at the end?

Comment: @BennyThadikaran https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html%5Fmono/find.html#Multiple-Files

Comment: Thanks i will check it, give it quick test and get back.